# How are char ** objects saved?

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, memory

Today, I asked me, how `char **` objects are saved in memory or in binary files. I tested that with the following code snippet:

```
char **array  = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));

array[0] = "Foo";         // Length: 3
array[1] = "Long string"; // Length: 11
array[2] = "Bar";         // Length: 3   => Full length: 17

int length = 17;
```

I write this array to a file:

```
FILE *file = fopen(...);
fwrite(array, length, 1, file);
fclose(file);
```

The great thing is that when I read again this array from file with the following code, the string lengths are read successfully without saving more than 17 bytes.

```
FILE *file   = fopen(...);
int   length = 17;

char **array = (char *)malloc(length);

int index        = 0;
int parsedLength = 0;
while (parsedLength < length)
{
    char *string       = array[index];
    int   stringLength = strlen(string);

    printf("%i: \"%s\" (%i)\n", index, string, stringLength);

    parsedLength += stringLength;
    ++index;
}
```

I get an output that equals:

```
0: "Foo" (3)
1: "Long string" (11)
2: "Bar" (3)
```

How does the compiler know, how long each string in the array is?

Comment: Your program cannot possibly have produced those results, as the strings never got written to the file. Heck, the code you posted doesn't even read from the file. So this is a troll post.

Comment: `char**` isn't an object, it's a pointer.  Bytes are saved in files.

Comment: Next time you ask a question at SO, **post the actual code you ran**, don't reconstruct it from memory, or edit it with a bunch of ellipses. This is especially important for rank beginners who have very little understanding of C and are inclined to have all sorts of mistaken ideas that they don't realize are mistaken.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pointers are saved to a file like numbers (or better addresses) so the fact that your code works is an illusion created by the fact that you are probably saving and loading them inside the same program in the same run (so since these string are literals, their address is mostly fixed in data segment).

What you are doing is completely wrong because array's layout in memory is the following (I'm assuming 4 bytes pointers):

```
XXXXXXXX YYYYYYYY ZZZZZZZZ ( = 12 bytes)
   ^        ^        ^
   |        |       pointer to "Bar"
   |      pointer to "Long String"
 pointer to "Foo"
```

but you are saving 17 bytes onto the file, 12 of which are just memory addresses.

To correctly save strings in the file you will certainly need to store the whole data contained and its length. Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; ++i) {
  char *string = array[i];
  unsigned int length = strlen(string);
  fwrite(&length, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, out);
  fwrite(string, sizeof(char), length, out);
}

for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; ++i {
  unsigned int length;
  fread(&length, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, in);
  array[i] = calloc(sizeof(char), length);
  fread(array[i], sizeof(char), length, in);
}
```

Comment: So to save a string array like the one with "Foo", "Long string" and "Bar" I have to implement my own array structure?

Comment: @PaulA.Warkentin Why are you posting troll questions? The code you posted cannot conceivably have produced the results you claim.

Comment: @JimBalter - Unfortunately it could behave like this - but only if the reading and writing are done in the same run of the executable. The pointers read will likely point at the same static literals that were written. It's still "wrong" on so many levels, but it's possible.

Comment: @Roddy, no, it can't, because the OP's code sets `array` to the result of malloc before printing its content and never reads into it. The OP obviously has not posted the actual code ... which probably just prints the same array without changing it ... or it might reread the same addresses, as you suggest. But why guess when the OP posts such crap?

Comment: @JimBalter: actually `array` is malloc'ed but then its contents are set to pointers to string literals, then these pointers are saved to the file so the fact that `array` has a dynamic address doesn't come into play.

Comment: Jack, you're not paying attention ... read what I wrote again: "the OP's code sets array to the result of malloc before printing its content" -- there are TWO mallocs in the posted code.

Comment: @JimBalter and Jack. I think we're *all* right :-( The OPs code has no `fread`, so we're all assuming stuff. There isn't a 'complete runnable example' to critique, so you're right that the code 'as posted' can't do this. More likely accidental than trolling, or 99.9% of SO Q's would be trolls...

Comment: @JimBalter: I just assumed there's a `fread` before the print loop.

Comment: @Roddy Yes, we're all right ... all of these are *possible* reasons for the code that the OP **never posted** doing what it did.

Comment: Why not assume instead that the OP didn't actually do a malloc? Since the OP **didn't post the code**, either of these are possible ... or an infinity of other possibilities.

Comment: @Roddy I consider posting code that wasn't actually run, along with purported output, to be a troll. 99.9% of SO Q's don't fit that category. But I'll admit that it probably wasn't *intended* to mislead us, and that Jack has the most plausible explanation for the secret code.

Answer (score 3):

In don't think your program works.
Try to write a new program which read your file, or try to open the binary file with an hex editor. The strings aren't present in it.
`char ** array` is an array of pointer not an array of char and its size is 3*4 = 12 on 32 bits common environment.